# What's the difference between MethodBeforeAdvice and @Before?

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

In spring AOP there are @Before (to be used with @Aspect) but also there is `MethodBeforeAdvice`. What's the difference and how to use the second one?

Comment: There is none. In fact when using AspectJ and a `@Before` with Spring AOP, that actually gets translated into a `MethodBeforeAdvice`.

Answer (score 0):

There three different approaches which are used to intercept before execution of method/s

- Implements MethodBeforeAdvice interface
- Using pointcut expression (XML configuration)
- Using Annotations i.e.; (@Aspect / @Before)

All are doing same thing.